# javascript reset an interval

Tags: javascript, setinterval, reset

I need to be able to call this function to reset the interval.

I know this has been asked before.  But the answer given at
[Javascript - Reset setInterval back to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8126466/1462490)
is not working for me.

Here is the code that I tried:

```
function startTimer(){
    clearInterval(interval);    
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        advanceSlide();
    }, 5000);
};
```

I call that at the beginning of my page to start a slideshow that changes every 5 seconds. and I use this code to call it again, witch I expected would reset that 5 seconds.

```
onclick=startTimer();>
```

The onclick does one other thing too, but this is what is not working.  The other action takes place but the interval does not change, its still going based off the same portion of 5 seconds that was left before I clicked.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to declare the variable outside the function...

```
var interval;

function startTimer() {
    clearInterval(interval);    
    interval = setInterval(advanceSlide, 5000);
}
```

Otherwise it is lost when the function exits.

Comment: Thanks @Rocket. Missed those when I deleted the anonymous func, then StackOverflow made me prove my humanity.

Comment: Wait, so you're *not* a robot?

Comment: @Rocket: I *am* a robot, but I fooled 'em.

Comment: Thank you! that is perfect.  I love this site, it is so awesome for learning.

Comment: Just implemented changes and my script is fully functional.  Thanks for your help.