# How to display a pop up after 10 seconds of inactivity

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display a price alarm pop up after 10 seconds of inactivity of user. Right now the pop up appears only on click. I want to replace it.

I tried my best but couldn't get it done.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var idleInterval = setInterval(inActiveTimer, 1000);
  $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
    idleTime = 0;
  });
  $(this).keypress(function (e) {
    idleTime = 0;
  });
  $(".sleepy-close, .sleepy-overlay, .sleepy-wake-up").click(function () {
    $(".sleepy-overlay").hide();
    clearInterval(idleInterval);
  });
});
```

The last part of the code leads to click enabled pop up. How can I replace it with automatic pop up which occurs after 10 seconds of inactivity.

Comment: What do you define as "inactivity"? 10 seconds of no events being fired?

Comment: Possible duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/how-to-detect-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly

Comment: check my below code it might help you bro.

Comment: refer the url. this is duplicate  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/how-to-detect-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly

Answer (score 2):

this will help you to capture 10 sec of inactivity in screen.change the code as such u need .

```js
document.body.innerText = "hello count the seconds";
setIdleTimeout(10000, function() {
    document.body.innerText = "Where did you go?";
}, function() {
    document.body.innerText = "Welcome back!";
});



function setIdleTimeout(millis, onIdle, onUnidle) {
    var timeout = 0;
    startTimer();

    function startTimer() {
        timeout = setTimeout(onExpires, millis);
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", onActivity);
        document.addEventListener("keypress", onActivity);
    }
    
    function onExpires() {
        timeout = 0;
        onIdle();
    }

    function onActivity() {
        if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
        else onUnidle();
        //since the mouse is moving, we turn off our event hooks for 1 second
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove", onActivity);
        document.removeEventListener("keypress", onActivity);
        setTimeout(startTimer, 1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To reset a `setInterval`, you need to clear it and set it again. Use the following code:

```js
// Instead of idleTime = 0
clearInterval(idleInterval);
idleInterval = setInterval(inActiveTimer, 10000);
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8126515/11168593) for more info

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 var idleTime = 0;

 $(document).ready(function () {

  var idleInterval = setInterval(function(){ 
      if(idleTime >= 10){
        $(".sleepy-overlay").hide(); // enabling the popup 
        idleTime = 0;
      }else{ 
        idleTime++;
      } 
    }, 1000); 

  $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
   idleTime = 0;
  });

  $(this).keypress(function (e) {
   idleTime = 0;
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Pure JavaScript approach**

You can keep a timer for 10 seconds using `setTimeout` and clear it whenever their is activity and restart it immediately.

```js
var timeout;

function resetTimer(){
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  console.log("Clearing timer because of activity");
  timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    alert("Done with 10 Seconds!");
    //Trigger your popup here
  }, 10000);
}

document.onmousemove = resetTimer;
document.onkeypress = resetTimer;
//You can add more activity event listeners like click etc.
```