# Resetting a Timer Back to 0 from Counter?

Tags: javascript, counter, setinterval, reset

I have been googling for a solution for this problem, but many suggestions that I have found either freezes the counter or does nothing. counter.innerHTML = 0 just resumes where it left off after a second.

Here is my code:

```
let reset = document.getElementById('reset')
let counter = document.getElementById('counter')
let num = 0;

let timer = setInterval(countUp, 1000);
function countUp() {
    counter.innerHTML = num++
}
//Reset timer
reset.addEventListener('click', stuff) 
function stuff() {
    clearInterval(timer)
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset the setInterval timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126466/how-do-i-reset-the-setinterval-timer)

Answer (score 1):

What you have is mostly working, you just need to

- clear the internal
- reset the innerHtml to 0

```js
let reset = document.getElementById('reset')
let counter = document.getElementById('counter')
let num = 0;

let timer = setInterval(countUp, 1000);

function countUp() {
  counter.innerHTML = num++
}

//Reset timer
reset.addEventListener('click', stuff)

function stuff() {
  counter.innerHTML = 0;
  clearInterval(timer)
}
```

```html
<button id="reset">reset</button>

<div id="counter" />
```

Comment: Appreciate the help.  Unfortunately, it only freezes the counter when pressing the reset button.

Comment: what do you mean `only freezes`? the code stops the incrementing and reset back to 0

Answer (score 1):

It's probably useful to put the logic that changes what you see in the page content in its own function: this will help you think about each part of the problem independently:

```js
let resetBtn = document.getElementById('reset');
let counter = document.getElementById('counter');
let num = 0;

// Start the timer
let timer = setInterval(countUp, 1000);

// Use this to update the DOM (page content)
function updateUI () {
  counter.textContent = num;
}

function countUp () {
  // Increment the number
  num += 1;
  // Update the DOM
  updateUI();
}

function reset () {
  // Stops the interval
  clearInterval(timer);
  // Reset the number
  num = 0;
  // Update the DOM
  updateUI();
}

// Update the UI the first time (before the counter reaches 1)
updateUI();

// Add the reset functionality to the button
resetBtn.addEventListener('click', reset);
```

```html
<div id="counter"></div>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Most of it help.  I removed clearInterval(timer), and replaced updateUI() with countUp() inside the reset function block.  I also started num at -1 so the counter begins at 0.