# Print form every 30 minutes

Tags: php, forms

I want to echo a form every 30 minutes each day for 18 repetition each day and this repetition will appear each 30 minutes and when the form appear the user will check the checkbox and submit the form and when he submits the form the form disappears and this will be do it 18 repetition per day.

I tried this code but it not show me any thing it still running without any output:

```
$dailydatetime=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$echo_time = time();
$interval = 1*60;
  while(true){
    if ($echo_time + $interval >= time()){
      echo "<form method='Post' action=''>";
      echo"<input type='checkbox' name='check' value=''>"  ;
      echo"<input type='submit' name='add' value='Check'>";  
      echo"</form>";  
      $echo_time = time(); 
    }

  }
```

Comment: Where is the jquery part?

Comment: Where is the Ajax and not the cleaning Kind.

Comment: @ka_lin i didn't use any jquery  but i add jquery maybe i need it in my code but i don't know

Comment: PHP should not be used for waiting because there are a limited amount of connections to a server and this loop will consume 1 CPU thread for a single user, use JavaScript timer events.

Comment: You need some javascript because php is compiled server side so displaying the form every 30 min means that is a front-end solution: use native js setInterval(), ajax via jquery and get back if you have problems.

Comment: @ka_lin can you please aid me with this because i don't have a big experience in javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579762/setinterval-by-the-minute-on-the-minute and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575928/ajax-response-inside-a-divshould help